# Parse JSON data with JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json.net

There are a lot of questions about this out there, but I couldn't find a solution to my problem.

I have JSON that looks like this:

```
{
"index":[
  {
     "Color":"Blue",
     "URL":"SomeURL",

     "Persons":[
        {
           "name":"Charlie",
           "Country":"Denmark",
           "Security number":"25663456"
        }
     ],

     "Color":"Green",
     "URL":"SomeURL",

     "Persons":[
        {
           "name":"Putin",
           "Country":"Russia",
           "Security number":"78495832"
         }
       ],
    ],
  } 
 "total":"2"
}
```

The only JSON data I can access is `index` and `total`.

How do I access and print out ONLY `name`, `Country` or `Color`?

Comment: index is an array. index[0].Color will give you "Blue" etc...

Comment: FYI, this isn't valid JSON; you're closing a block before an array at the very end

Comment: @DrewMcGowen im sorry, since I wrote it down by looking at it, there could be some mistakes

Comment: "since I wrote it down by looking at it" You wrote it out by hand? Why didn't you copy and paste?

Comment: @weston
yeah, well the index array is several pages long, so I can't really copy and paste all that in here. therefore I made a few changes and shortened it a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

index is an array. index[0].Color will give you "Blue" etc...

Answer (score 1):

The index is an array of objects. To access it, you'll have to loop over it, or access each element by its index in the array. Then, you'll have access to the properties you have set on it in the feed.

You can do something like this if you're using the JSON.Net lib:

```
dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(target)
foreach(var item in jsonObj.index)
{
    string color = item.Color;
}
```